# Change Visio diagram properties in C#

Tags: c#, visio

I want to change the physical name of an entity in Visio through C#.

```
Shape1.Text="name";
```

This can change column names. I have tried it as:

```
Shape1.Name="name";
```

But it does not effect the physical name of the entity.
I want to add data through coding same like we put data manually in visio entity.

Comment: What do you mean by 'entity'?  Do you want to set the Name property of a shape or are you refering to an aspect of a particular template and stencil?  If it's the former, then bear in mind that Shape.Name gives you the local name, but Shape.NameU gives you the universal name.  See this link for more on NameU http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765535.aspx